# Подсчёт количества переходов для value SQL clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

У меня есть следующая таблица. Мне нужно посчитать count для переходов  one -> two , two -> one. Колонка Value содержит только два возможных значения:
one / two .
БД - clickhouse

```
time                        value

2022-09-19 04:03:06.845     one
2022-09-19 04:03:06.846     two
2022-09-19 04:03:08.055     two
2022-09-19 04:03:08.141     one
2022-09-19 04:03:08.160     one
2022-09-19 04:03:08.258     one
2022-09-19 04:03:08.757     two
2022-09-19 04:03:08.983     two
2022-09-19 04:03:12.051     two
2022-09-19 04:03:12.785     two
2022-09-19 04:03:12.860     one
```

То есть в данном случае должно получиться

```
count(*)
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickHouse не поддерживает LAG/LEAD, посему эмулируем через одно место:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN value = ANY(value) OVER (ORDER BY time 
                                              ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING 
                                                       AND 1 PRECEDING) 
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1 
                END) - 1
FROM tablename
```

Единицу вычитаем, потому что выражение считает и переход от несуществующей предначальной записи (для неё возвращается NULL) к самой первой.

Comment: Спасибо больше, за отклик!

Comment: Получаю следующую ошибку (
SQL Error [62] [07000]: Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 39 ('OVER') (line 1, col 39): OVER (ORDER BY time  
                                              ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING
                                                       A. Expected one of: token, DoubleColon, MOD, DIV, NOT, BETWEEN, LIKE, ILIKE, NOT LIKE, NOT ILIKE, IN, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN, GLOBAL NOT IN, IS, AND, OR, QuestionMark, alias, AS, THEN, end of query. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 22.4.5.9 (official build))
, server ClickHouseNode

Comment: есть мысли в чём может быть дело?

Comment: @ditrauth Возможно, ClickHouse просто неспособен переварить оконную функцию как аргумент агрегатной. Тогда вынесите CASE в CTE, а во внешнем запросе только суммируйте.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помошь!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [sequenceCount](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/parametric-functions/#sequencecountpatterntime-cond1-cond2-)-функцию:

```sql
SELECT
    sequenceCount('(?1)(?2)')(time, value = 'one', value = 'two') AS one_two_count,
    sequenceCount('(?1)(?2)')(time, value = 'two', value = 'one') AS two_one_count,
    one_two_count + two_one_count AS result
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        toUInt64(toDateTime64(data.1, 3)) AS time,
        data.2 AS value
    FROM 
    ( /* emulate the test data set */
        SELECT arrayJoin([('2022-09-19 04:03:06.845', 'one'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:06.846', 'two'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:08.055', 'two'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:08.141', 'one'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:08.160', 'one'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:08.258', 'one'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:08.757', 'two'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:08.983', 'two'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:12.051', 'two'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:12.785', 'two'), ('2022-09-19 04:03:12.860', 'one')]) AS data
    )
)

/*
┌─one_two_count─┬─two_one_count─┬─result─┐
│             2 │             2 │      4 │
└───────────────┴───────────────┴────────┘
*/
```